# FTP deployment options don't show up when I change modules in IntelliJ Idea Ultimate

Tags: intellij-idea

I have a project which I created in a website (Website A). I also created an FTP deployment connection to a remote host and that works fine.

I then added another website (Website B) to my project as modules because they share a lot of code between them. I added another FTP deployment option for this new website.

When I want to upload to my server from Website A, I select `Deployment > Upload To` and can see both my remote host FTP connections to choose from. But when I open a file from Website B or select a file in Website B's modules, I cannot find ANY of my deployment FTP connections.

Why is that? Can only one module have deployment options? In that case do I need to create a new project for each website even though I need them all open in one workspace?

Comment: You must have set wrong deployment mappings for the Website B module.
Mappings are what assigns deployment configurations to modules, if they set correctly you can deploy to different sites both isolated and nested modules.
Here's a screencast showing how it's supposed to be configured: http://recordit.co/ekDGPnjhOb

Comment: That is super helpful @EugeneMorozov thank you! I managed to get it working after looking at your video

Comment: Glad I've been of some help. Will re-post this as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have set wrong deployment mappings for the Website B module. Mappings are what assigns deployment configurations to modules, if they set correctly you can deploy to different sites both isolated and nested modules.

Here's a screencast of how it's supposed to be configured: http://recordit.co/ekDGPnjhOb